# Variables are not being passed by reference in yt-minify.php

Tags: responsive-web-design

I recently moved my joomla-based website from my computer (WAMP SERVER) to a shared hosting server on the internet. But i keep getting an error below my site's header that goes thus:

**"*Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /home_directory/hostname/publicfolder/plugins/system/yt/includes/libs/yt-minify.php on line 179*"**

What do i do? I have set the permissions for both yt-minify.php and the config.php for the YT Framework to 777.

Kindly help. #Joomla

Answer (score 1):

Strict standard errors is something a lot of people have asked about. I hope you did some research first.

Basically, your live server is most likely running PHP 5.4+, where by default, strict error are set to appear. They're not an issue so you can simply turn them off.

Firstly, go into your Joomla Global Configuration, and ensure you've seet Error Reporting to **default**, then check to see if the error still occurs.

If it does, you'll need to disable them by either:

- Opening the server *php.ini* and setting `error_reporting` to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT`

**or**

- Adding `php_value error_reporting 30711` to your `.htaccess` file

**or**

- Adding `ini_set('display_errors', '0'); error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` to your template's *index.php*, however this is not recommended

Comment: Thanks! I contacted my hosting server and they switched my PHP account. I had 5.4. native PHP version before that. so it was switched to custom 5.4. version, it has different php settings that native 5.4.